# urllib.request.urlopen, specific content not returned

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

With this request I get back the page source, but the IP-Address/Hostname/Location fields are empty. Why, and how can I get these?

```
import urllib.request
s = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.whatsmyipaddress.net").read()
txt = str(s)
fs = open('myip-net.htm', 'w')
fs.write(txt)
fs.close()
```

Comment: I think it has to do with the way the website is set up. Even when you view the HTML yourself, the location tag does not directly display the value for the fields.

Comment: Use this url: `http://www.whatsmyipaddress.net/?func=proxy&sid=ID`. It returns a json response with the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

**whatsmyipaddress.net** uses JavaScript to retrieve the IP-Address/Hostname/Location fields. The JavaScript only executes when you navigate to the page via a web browser. You are grabbing the HTML file itself and writing its content to another file, which does not execute JS. Also, that HTML file will not load properly on your local machine without copies of the CSS and JS files the HTML is linking to.

If you only care about getting your IP and location data back, I'd recommend requesting data from a public API instead.

ex: **http://ip-api.com/json**

Comment: I assumed this was the case. Actually I don't care about the IP address or this specific web page, but want to learn how to grab such content response.

Comment: @bretddog Selenium is a good way to go if you want to grab the rendered page after the JS has run. You can use a headless browser like PhantomJS if you don't want a browser window to pop open while running. Note, PhantomJS will need to be installed on your machine in order to run. Check this link for reference: [PhantomJS with Selenium](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try selenium instead:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.whatsmyipaddress.net")
ip = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p').text
```

returns:

```
'12.23.34.45' # the ip
```

I always have this problem when first trying for example BeautifulSoup and extracting something. I think @Daniel Wasilewski is right. His answer is good.

Note: you would need chromedriver.exe also to make something like this work. You don't have to use Chrome; Firefox would work as well.

**Update**:

I realize this is not an ideal answer but unless you know of another way to deal with javascript, this this is simply "one way" of possibly others.

Selenium has a "headless" option but it still opens what looks like a command window (on Windows). It's called **phantomjs**. I won't detail everything there is to know about it; there's lots of info here on SO.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://www.whatsmyipaddress.net")
ip = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p').text
print(ip)
```

Comment: hmm.. I'm sure it works, but there should be a way to do this in python..

Comment: well, :) ok.. my reaction was I felt such dependency was hiding what I wanted to learn. But perhaps it's more complex to do than I thought..

Comment: Chrome browser loads/opens when running this. Is that expected?, and can it be suppressed?

Comment: Yes, that is expected. It can be suppressed with phantomjs - a "headless" solution - but a window still pops up when executed. See update.

Comment: Would it perhaps be more appropriate to pursue this with JS/node..?